# Is it possible to use Selenium Webdriver to stimulate several users hitting a site?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, load, load-balancing

I have a crucial question please. Is it possible to use selenium webdriver to stimulate like 50 users hitting on a site at the same time? If not any recommendations on what to use for this test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver is not recommended, but is able to do it. I'd suggest JMeter to do something like this. It has a simple interface and is relatively easy to use after a couple of YouTube tutorials.

Comment: Thanks! we are going to go with this!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to better define the "at the same time" piece as normal populations of users arrive and depart chaotically with varying times between requests.   The client server model is pretty much built around this chaotic use and the availability of resources to service B when A in idle on its request stream.  You can easily pick out inexperienced performance testing scripts when the think time and iteration pacing go to zero when representing a population of users and not automated agents.

Do not take my word for this.  Look at your own HTTP logs for an application which has a human user population and your will begin to understand this chaotic usage.

As to the 50 users, pick just about any performance testing tool on the market to do the work.  All of the existing commercial tools have community editions which will scale to that level, in addition to the open source tools.  The large advantage of the commercial tools is that you typically get a single app installation with all integrations worked out.  The open source is a mashup of multiple tools if you want the same functionality.

No matter what tool you pick, open source or commercial, you will face a steep learning curve if this is not your core job with a good amount of experience behind your effort.  Plan for that efficiency drop.